# What are the Spring Web Flow advantages?

Tags: spring-webflow

Can someone help me understand the advantages of Spring Web Flow.
What I have understood is

1. All the flows can be centrally configured in an XML file.
2. Need not have an overhead of carrying over the data from one request to another as it can be done by flow scope.
3. It helps especially in cases like Breadcrumbs navigation.
4. Flows can be further divided into Sub Flows to reduce the complexity.

Are there any other ones which I am have not tweaked into?

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't suggest working with Spring Webflow unless you already understand Spring MVC.  Some things are not very intuitive/not built.  For example, I still don't know how to properly resume a flow to the last place the user left off.  Configuring the XML is different from how you would configure a normal Spring config too.  Your URL also becomes one that's based on executions, so it's not easy to reference a page directly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm going to play devil's advocate and say don't use it for anything other than simple use cases. Simple use cases meaning no ajax calls, no modal dialogs, no partial updates just standard html forms/flows for simple persistence (i.e page A -> page B -> Page C where each 'page' maps to a view-state definition in a 1 to 1 relationship all defined in the same flow xml file).

**Spring webflow cons:**

1. Yes everything is in xml files in theory it is suppose to be simple but when you have multiple flow xml files each with multiple state definitions and possibly subflow definitions it can become cumbersome to maintain or easily determine what the sequential logic of a flow is. (kind of like the old "GOTO operator" where any part of a flow logic can jump back to any previously or later defined part making the flow logic although seemingly "sequential" in xml... un-intuitive to follow)
2. Some features of Spring Webflow's documentation are unintuitive or flat out undocumented leading to hours of trial and error. For instance, exception handeling, usauge of 'output' tag (only works in subflow->back to parent caller undocumented), sending back flash view responses to a user is also unintuitive and uses a different container than Spring MVC (many times when a flow ends you want to send a msg to the user that is defined in a controller outside of webflow... but since the flow ended you can't do it with in spring webflow using flashScope container), etc...
3. Adding subflows although sounds good does not reduce complexity actually increases it. Due to the way subflows are defined. Definitions are long and complex and can be confusing when you have many end-states in both the main parent flow and the child subflows.
4. Initial setup and configuration can be painful if integrating with certain 3rd party view frameworks like Apache Tiles or Theymeleaf... I recall spending a few hours if not days on this.
5. State snapshots (Saving the user's input between pages) although a powerful feature from Flow A's view-state_1 <-> Flow A's view-state_2 and vise versa. This does not work between Main Flow A <-> Sub Flow B and vise versa... forcing the developer to manually bind (or rather hack) saving a user's state between Parent main flow's <-> subflows.
6. Debugging application logic placed inside webflow can be difficult. For instance, in webflow you can assign variables and perform condition checks all using SPEL inside the xml but this tends to be a pitfall. Over time you learn to avoid placing application logic inside the actual webflow xml and only use the xml to call service class methods and to place the returned values in the various scopes (again this hard learned lesson/best practice is undocumented). Also, because you are executing logic using SPEL... refactoring classes, method names, or variables sometimes silently break your application significantly increasing your development time.
7. fragment rendering... a powerful but unintuitive feature of webflow. Setting up fragment rendering was 1 of the most painful things I had to do with webflow. The documentation was lacking. I think this feature could easily go in the pros side if it was better documented and easy to setup. I actually documented how to use this feature via stackoverflow... [How to include a pop-up dialog box in subflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000963/how-to-include-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-subflow/29114719#29114719)
8. Static URLs per flow. If your flow has multiple views defined with in 1 flow your URL will not change navigating from view-state to view-state. This can be limiting if you want to control or match the content of the page with a dynamic url.
9. If your flow is defined in "/WEB-INF/flows/doSumTing/sumting-flow.xml" and your "base-path" is set to "WEB-INF/flows". Then to navigate to your flow you goto `http://<your-host>/<your-webapp-name-if-defined>/doSumTing` . The flow file name is completely ignored and not used in the URL at all. Although clear now I found this unintuitive when I first started.

**Spring Webflow pros:**

1. concept of "scope" containers flowScope, viewScope, flashScope, sessionScope and having easy access to these containers **WITH IN A FLOW** gives the developer flexibility as these are accessible from anywhere and are mutable.
2. Easily define states view-state,action-state,decision-state,end-state which clearly defines what each state is doing but as mentioned in the cons... if your application is complex and has MANY different states and transitions constantly Going back and forth... this can clutter your -flow.xml file makes it hard to read or follow the sequential logic. It's only easy if you have simple use cases with a small number of state definitions.
3. Seldom used but a powerful feature of webflow is flow inheritance. Common flow functionality across multiple flows can be defined in a single abstract parent flow and extended by child flows (similar to an abstract class definition in java). This feature is nice with regards to the DRY principle if you have many flows that share common logic.
4. Easily defined validation rules and support for JSR-303 (but Spring MVC has this as well)
5. The output tag can be used to send POJOs back and forth between Main flow <-> subflow. This feature is nice because the parameters don't need to be passed through the url via get/post and can pass as many POJOs as you wish.
6. Clearly defined views. What the view name is and which model variable it is being mapped to (e.g  `<view-state id="edit" view="#{flowScope.modelPathName}/editView" model="modelObj">` ). Also in the example just demonstrated can use preprocessing expressions for viewnames or most arguments in webflow... nice feature though not very well documented :/

**Conclusion:** Spring Webflow project was a good idea and sounds great on paper but the cons make it cumbersome to work with in complex use cases increasing development time significantly. Since a better solution exists for complex use cases (Spring MVC) to me it is not worth investing heavily in web flow because you can achieve the same results with Spring MVC and with a faster development time for both complex and simple use cases. Morever, Spring MVC is actively maintained, has better documentation, and a larger user community. Maybe if some of my cons are addressed it would tip the scales in Webflow's favor but until then I will recommend Spring MVC over webflow.

Note: I might be missing some things but this is what I came up with off the top of my head.

Comment: i'll edit answer or add more to cons/pros as I or others suggest.

Comment: is there a work-around for using Spring MVC and having back-button support?  You mention this in your Conclusion.

Comment: @bphilipnyc no I actually didn't mention that in the conclusion but I did in the cons section #5. It is a nice feature but for me personally I seldom use it (thus seldom value it) but I suppose other's value webflow for that. So if that is a must have feature in an upcoming project then yes use webflow but I genuinely believe that to be a minority of use cases. In Spring MVC, the closest (but still far from matching snapshots) thing you can do is use the @SessionAttribute("myModel") annotation.

Comment: Right - I was referring to your mentioning Spring MVC in the conclusion.  It sounds like we agree.

Comment: @bphilipnyc yea webflow is still a promising project. Maybe if they ever get around to overhauling for a major revision (3.0) and optionally have tighter Spring MVC integration I think I would easily go back to using it for all my use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you can use the back button and retain state up to the number of snapshots you choose to store.

You also may find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345013/when-does-it-make-sense-to-use-spring-webflow-on-top-of-spring-mvc) useful.

Comment: Saverio, how does it not answer the question?  Using the back button to store snapshots is an advantage to Spring Web Flow that is missing from the list and the primary reason I personally used it on my project.